Where is "Corridoio 1 \ Passageway 1" at the Vatican museums?
I bought a ticket to see the Vatican Museums and Sistine Chapels. The text says I should access "CORRIDOIO1\PASSAGEWAY1". Where exactly is this corridor/passageway? I've checked the official and unofficial maps and couldn't find any details. The Vatican museum seems to have at least two entrances (I think?), so I want to be sure I go to the right one.


you can download the detailed map of the Vatican museums from here: https://www.museivaticani.va/content/dam/museivaticani/pdf/visita_musei/servizi_visitatori/mappa_musei_vaticani.pdf! Here in the lefthand corner you find the exact location of the entrance (as it was already shown on google maps before)!

I went to the museum so I can now provide an answer.
Entrances/Passageways 1, 2 and 3 are at this little square in front of the northern entrance to the Vatican museums. It's at the corner of Via Tunisi and Viale Vaticano. Exact GPS location: 41.906922, 12.453507.
Entrance 1 is for people who bought their tickets online. Entrances 2 and 3 are for organized tour groups.


Yes - I was in this exact same position last month. I was worried to get confused due to my poor Italian (it quickly decomposes into Spanish with an Italian accent).
The good news is - it's less confusing than I worried "in real life." What I would say is - as you approach the museum, you will see very long lines. These are generally for those that did not pre-purchase tickets. Proceed to the front and you should see signs matching entrance numbers. If you have your purchased tickets pulled up on your phone, they will quickly point you in the right direction.
Many of the museum staff will speak English. As the locals always remind me, "Parli molto male l'italiano!"


Where exactly is this corridor/passageway?

Based on this answer found here:

Can I use the door leading from Vatican museum to St. Peter's Basilica? - Travel Stack Exchange


when you exit the Sistine Chapel, take the exit on the far right corner, instead of the one on the near left corner.

On the image below, this will be on the right hand side of the image, going down towards the 'La Pietà di Michelangelo'.



How to Visit the Vatican Museums & St. Peter’s Basilica in 2024 – Earth Trekkers


There is a door that leads to a passageway that connects the Sistine Chapel directly to St. Peter's Basilica. Only certain tour groups are allowed to take this exit. The main exit leads you to a long hallway that takes you back towards the entrance of the Vatican Museums

