Vatican museums tickets
I'm going to visit the Vatican museums with 20 students.
I have some questions about tickets and passageway.
Some students bought Vatican tickets from the site 'Get Your Guide (maybe travel agency)' and others bought from the Vatican's online site.
Q1. I saw the passage written on tickets is different. So can we go around together inside the Vatican Museums? Tickets from Get Your Guide are passageway 3 but tickets from the Vatican's site are passage 1. Is the distance between passageways 1 and 3 very far?
Q2. Are Vatican museums museum tickets from 'Get Your Guide' okay to enter the Vatican? I'm worried about that because we didn't use the official site.
I'm not good at English so I apologize if the question is weird. Thank you for reading my question!

It is possible that the passage numbers refer to entry with or without long queue. Once inside you are free to walk around, though they may have some policy on tour groups.

E.g. they write you need to hire headsets for guided groups of more than 10 people, here: https://m.museivaticani.va/content/museivaticani-mobile/en/organizza-visita/consigli-utili.html

But see also this answer: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/189238/where-is-corridoio-1-passageway-1-at-the-vatican-museums

Disclosure: My ticket from April had "Passageway 2" written on it

thanks a lot! However, we are planning to travel inside the Vatican without a professional guide, do we must have to rent earphones if our group are more than 20 people?

When I was in Vatican museum I believe there was a guide and a strict route to be followed, so it is quite possible you will not be able to go around together.
